# What is the "next generation plugin" for Java

Tags: java, applet, browser-plugin, next-generation-plugin

What is the "next generation plugin" for Java and how is it different from the classic plugin?

Strangely, there is only one generic plugin on Mac OS X, so is this distinction only on Windows, or does linux also have two plugins?

I also noticed that Firefox is only telling me to update the classic plugin, so I must wonder how different the two plugins are if only one can be compromised. Or else Firefox is making a mistake, and they're both vulnerable.

I am also interested if this distinction affects any Applets adversely.

Comment: There was a "new" Applet model introduced in Java 1.6.18 or so; in effect it is a Java Web Start (JWS) container hosted in the browser. Unfortunately Sun really butchered the [earlier] Applet implementations. I would recommend using the container provided with the official JRE, if available. (It works well-enough in Windows and Linux, I don't know about others.)

Comment: @pst how does the applet security policy work if it's run under webstart? Wouldn't that make it worse?

Comment: Applets were never very "trusted" to begin with. I'm not exactly sure of the nuances these days though -- thankfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the "next generation plugin" for Java and how is it different from the classic plugin?

See the [applet info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) for a link to the page describing it.